# Repetative "If statements" save and reuse results

Tags: c#, if-statement, razor, save, code-reuse

I am in Visual Studio view of the MVC (razor code).  I have the same bool "if statemant" being used several times in different area's of the code.  I have been told that I could save the results of the first if statement and reuse the results so I don't have to write the "if statement" several times over.

How do I save the results of the first if statement and reuse the results below?

```
var IsManager = someRole;
var IsTeamLead= someOtherRole;

if(IsManager || ITeamLead)
{
 //Veiew this resticted content on the application;
}

//Code;
//Code;

if(IsManager || IsTeamLead)
{
 //Veiew more resticted content on the application;
}

//Little more code;
//Little more Code;

if(IsManager || Is TeamLead)
{
 //Veiew this content too;
}

//Little more code
//Little more code
//Little more code

if(IsManager || IsTeamLead)
{
 //Veiew this content;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the suggestion they gave you, but one possibility is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Introduce a new variable which you check like `bool isAuthorizedToView = someRole || someOtherRole;` Now you can use everywhere `if(isAuthorizedToView){...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool isManagerOrTeamLead = IsManager || ITeamLead;
```

Then...

```
if(isManagerOrTeamLead)
{
 //Veiew this resticted content on the application;
}
```

Comment: rory.ap Thanks for confirming!  My thought on that one.